# CSS Dropdown menu align not working

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a dropdown menu written in only CSS. It should look like item|item|item| <- page corner. But it now gets the width of it's dropdown. I attach an image to make it clean:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Esv.jpg

so the power button should be on the right and it's dropdown should go left.

My code(CSS):

```
span.topnavright {
    color:white;
    float: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 0.7em;
    padding-left: 0.7em;
    display: table-cell;
}
span.topnavright:hover {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: #464741;
}
div.menutop {
    background: #464741;
    color: white;
    visibility: hidden;
    right: 0px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
span.topnavright:hover > div.menutop {
    visibility: visible;
    position: relative;
}
```

ANd my HTML:

```
 <span class="topnavright">
                <i class="icon-power"></i>
                <div class="menutop">
                    LOLOLO<br />
                    kdsajfeiéfnédskvmdasévjdsaésvdasjdsf
                </div>
             </span>
 <span class="topnavright">
                haha
             </span>
 <span class="topnavright">
                haha
             </span>
```

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m46F6/2/

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your css

```
.icon-power{float:right;}
```

Comment: You'll probably need to set some widths too--otherwise your power-icon is going to be the width of the drop-down text, which I assume you don't want. Use `display:inline-block;`

Comment: what you want exactly can you show me the image of desired result?

Comment: @AbdulMalik:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/WvP29.jpg
The items have fixed space before and after them.. and the dropdown does not modify their visiblity. does not push them

Comment: but this image is different form fiddle

Comment: @AbdulMalik I just drawed. Or which image are you talking about?

Comment: @AbdulMalik Yes, that was after I added the `.icon-power{....` stuff. Noq I have this problem